# Bootstrap 4 positioning, iframe and button elements not aligning

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working with an iframe music player widget, with a button of my own next to it.

I can't seem to line them up, here's a screenshot:

[image: music player misaligned with skip button]

Here is (I think) all the code relevant to these elements:

```
HTML: 
    <div class="row fixed-top" id="mixRow">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="mixCol">
          <div id="mix-display">
            <iframe width="50%" height="60" id="my-widget-iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
          </div>
            <button class="btn-square" id="skipButton">Skip</button>
            <div id="weatherText"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

here is the Javascript that pops the music player into the iframe tag:

```
JS:
if (weatherCode > 950 && weatherCode < 956){
    $('#mix-display').html('<iframe width="100%" height="60" src=' + breezy[Math.floor(Math.random() * breezy.length)] + ' frameborder="0"></iframe>');
      }
```

And here is CSS for all the elements involved:

CSS:

```
#mixRow{
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 22%;
  height: 60px;
}

#mixCol{
  padding:0;
  margin-left: 0;
  height: 60px;
}

#mix-display{
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#skipButton{
  background-color: #333;
  border-color: #101418;
  border: 1px;
   font-family: Open Sans,sans-serif;
   font-size: 100%;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  }

button{
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn{
  color: white;
  background: rgba(230, 230, 260, 0.6);
  border-color: rgba(230, 230, 260, 0.6);
  border: none;
  border-style: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.btn:hover{
  background: rgba(200, 200, 260, 0.65);
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal easily by nesting the 2 items (the iframe and he skip button) as shown in the code snippet below.

You first put a `.row` into the column and then put 2 columns (`.col`) inside.

Put the `iframe` into the first column, the button into the second and give the second column the class `.col-auto` to make the column size adjust automatically as needed. Done!

If you want to center the button, add the classes `d-flex align-items-center` to its column.

To remove the gutters from the row I added the `no-gutters` class to it and also added the `bg-secondary` class to the `iframe` + the `bg-warning` to the button column to see what's going on.

Click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row fixed-top" id="mixRow">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="mixCol">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="mix-display" class="bg-secondary">
                        <iframe width="50%" height="60" id="my-widget-iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center bg-warning">
                    <button class="btn btn-square" id="skipButton">Skip</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="weatherText">Weather text goes here...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the vertical alignment issue perfectly. Now there's a pretty big space between the player and the button, for some reason. Any ideas? I'll start tinkering with it now!

Comment: Fixed it, I just had to up the width on the mix-display CSS property!